# Embedded HTML contains JavaScript function not getting called

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

In my scenario i am making an ajax request to get some data and then passing its result to some function you can see the code.

```
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    $.ajax({
        url: chartUrl,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function(result){
            UpdateChartArea(result, chartType);
            if(isTextMining){               
                         eval('ShowBreadCrmb_'identifier.substring(1) + '();');
            }
        },
        error: function(req, status, error) {

        }
    });
```

After embedding the HTML i want to call a JS function that is in that HTML. the HTML that i am embedding is present in a user control so to have a unique instance this is how my show bread crumb method look like

```
    function ShowBreadCrmb_<%= reportScale.ScaleID %>()
    {
    alert('LHJLH');
        var isTextMining = <%= TextMiningChart %>;
        if(isTextMining)
        {
            CreateTmBreadCrumb('<%= reportScale.NodeLevel %>','<%= reportScale.NodeName %>',topicList)
        }
    }
```

for more info what my updatechartarea does is

```
if (parent) {
    clearChildren(parent);
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = html;
    parent.appendChild(div);
}
```

I want to call the bread crumb function after update chart area function is called.

Comment: Are you getting any JS error .. You can check in error console / Firebug in firefox

Comment: @Ankur i am getting an js error that ShowBreadCrmb_103 is not found.

Comment: Ok.. can you check in "view source" that this method "ShowBreadCrmb_103" is there inside a script tag in HTML

Comment: yaa i had a debugged it in IE and it is showing it

Answer (score 0):

I would just change the function definition of `ShowBreadCrmb_...` to include parentheses after the closing bracket `}`. That should invoke it right after defining it.

e.g.

```
function ShowBreadCrmb_<%= reportScale.ScaleID %>()
{
alert('LHJLH');
    var isTextMining = <%= TextMiningChart %>;
    if(isTextMining)
    {
        CreateTmBreadCrumb('<%= reportScale.NodeLevel %>','<%= reportScale.NodeName %>',topicList)
    }
}();
```

Does that work?

Comment: no it is not working it is giving me the same error ShowBreadCrmb_119 is not defined

Comment: Is the javascript function completely valid? i.e. If you inspect it using Firebug after it has replaced the HTML, is the `ShowBreadCrmb_119()` function completely valid Javascript?

Comment: what do u mean by completely valid please specify?

Comment: I mean "Are there any syntax errors in the javascript that is produced?". You can test this by copying the javascript function definition in the HTML and pasting it into the Firebug console. If you click Run, it will tell you if there are any errors.